# SharePoint 2013 list workflow is not starting

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, workflow2013

I have a custom SharePoint 2013 workflow created by SharePoint Designer for a SharePoint Online List for new/update items.
The list has a SharePoint Form, from where the list item is created or updated.
When a list item is updated or created from the form, the workflow kicks in.

This was working fine for a year or so, now SharePoint 2013 Workflow does not starts.
All changes including update or create new item on the SharePoint list works, but workflow does not kicks in.
I even tried starting it manually for the newly created list item, but I get "Something went wrong. To try again, reload the page and then start the workflow" error message.
Even after refresh it still wont work.

Does anyone know how to fix it?
It was working fine a week ago, nothing changed on the form or the list or the workflow in the past three months.

**Flow:**
SharePoint list item is entered is created or modified by the SharePoint Form, once the list item is created or modified the custom SharePoint 2013 workflow kicks in.

Comment: Microsoft deprecated SP Workflow 2013 since a while.
From Nov, 1st, SP Workflows 2013 will be turned off for new tenant, meaning soon Microsoft would retire it from the O365 platform.
I advice you to migrate your SP Workflow on Power Automate.

Note: For your info, it happened to me after a migration from on-premise, the workflow works back few weeks after without any changes from my side.

Comment: @VladimirHerrlein so SharePoint Workflow 2013 wont work? It was working good till last week, and we got the info that its going away by Jul 2021.

Comment: Microsoft didn’t announced any official dates for the end of life of the 2013 workflow engine. We could assume the engine would be still available till the end of life of SP Designer 2013 and SP 2016 but without support in case of troubles. I advise you to raise a support ticket from the SharePoint Admin center.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Vladimir said, SP workflow 2013 is retiring in SharePoint Online.

> SharePoint 2013 workflows remain supported SharePoint 2013 workflows
> will remain supported, although deprecated.  However, we recommend
> customers move to Power Automate or other supported solutions, such as
> those from Preferred members of our Microsoft 365 Business Apps
> Partner Program.
>
> Starting in November 2020, SharePoint 2013 workflows will be turned
> off by default for new tenants. Microsoft will provide a PowerShell
> script to let customers to activate the SharePoint 2013-based workflow
> engine for tenant as needed.

Reference: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/office-end-of-support-blog/support-update-for-sharepoint-2010-workflows-in-microsoft-365/ba-p/1505453

I tested with a newly created workflow and it works fine. Have a try to create a new 2013 workflow and test it. If it still does not get triggered by any means, you will need to open a service request for it.